Group Policy Slow Link and Application Issues on Specific Workstations in Surveillance Training Classroom
I’m encountering an issue in a classroom setup used for training on surveillance systems that involve camera and radar applications. Each classroom has identical network layouts and PC configurations, but one specific workstation (Workstation 2) in each classroom is experiencing issues, while Workstation 1 functions normally.
Setup Details

Both classrooms have identical configurations, used for teaching surveillance systems that rely on networked camera and radar feeds.
Workstation 1 and Workstation 2 are used by the instructor for demonstrations, with Workstation 1 working as expected and Workstation 2 facing issues.

Issues Observed

Group Policy Slow Link Detection: Workstation 2 in both classrooms detects a slow link, which appears to interfere with proper Group Policy application.
Application Errors: On Workstation 2, a simulator software reliant on a camera feed and radar data fails to initialize. This issue is specific to Workstation 2, as the simulator works fine on Workstation 1.
Event Log Warnings: In Event Viewer on Workstation 2, I’m seeing warnings related to Security-SPP (license activation errors) and SecClt (possibly linked to Group Policy conflicts or configuration compliance).

Troubleshooting Steps Taken

Log Comparison: I compared Event Logs between Workstation 1 (working) and Workstation 2 (problematic) and noted the following discrepancies:
Workstation 2 shows repeated slow link detections, which Workstation 1 does not.
Warnings related to Security-SPP and SecClt appear only on Workstation 2, suggesting potential permission or configuration issues impacting policy application and network-dependent applications.
Configuration Review: I reviewed network and Group Policy configurations on both workstations but didn’t find significant configuration mismatches.
•   Network Diagnostics: Ran diagnostics on Workstation 2 to check for packet loss or latency but found no clear indication of a network fault specific to Workstation 2.

Request for Advice
Is my troubleshooting approach on the right track? I’d appreciate any insights on additional steps to:

Resolve the slow link detection on Workstation 2.
Address potential issues with Security-SPP and SecClt warnings in Event Viewer.
Ensure reliable initialization of the simulator software on Workstation 2.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Has anyone encountered similar Group Policy or network-dependent application issues in a training environment like this?
Thank you!

What is the throughout of the connection to the domain controller, and what speed is slow link detection configured for? The default if not configured is 500 kbps.

I can tell you 10 hours from now when i get back to my workplace
